# How can I transfer the eth that I'm mining with Geth to a wallet? (MEW)

Tags: wallets

I'm running Linux Mint.
I have tried following tutorials but nothing is happening other than my geth chaindata folder increasing in size. I also don't know how to join a pool with Geth. Also don't know how to check how much I've mined.
Total noob so please try to explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

The miner address can be configured with the get option `--miner.etherbase <address>`. If no address was supplied geth will mine to the first account created, those details are stored in a JSON file.

That file can be imported in any wallet that support that format. For example MyCrypto, MyEtherWallet and Metamask have that option. The transfer could be done from the geth command line but it is much easier from a wallet.

Comment: About the second part,how can i actually import it since i dont see anything about importing a file on mew/mycrypto or metamask

Comment: @aLEXXU Metamask has an import account, on type select JSON file, then a browse button will appear. In MyEtherWallet under "software wallet" there is a "Keystore" option that allows selecting the file. If using from a web page make sure the computer is reasonably secure.